# iOS OpenGL: Why has scaling my renderbuffer for retina shrunk my image, and how do I fix it?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, augmented-reality

I'm working on an augmented reality project using a Retina iPad but the two layers - the camera feed and the OpenGL overlay - are not making use of the high resolution screen. The camera feed is being drawn to a texture, which appears to be being scaled and sampled, where as the overlay is using the blocky 4 pixels scale up:

[image: Screen Scale Factor = 1]

I have looked through a bunch of questions and added the following lines to my EAGLView class.

To initWithCoder, before calling setupFrameBuffer and setupRenderBuffer:

```
    self.contentScaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

and in setupFrameBuffer

```
float screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
float width = self.frame.size.width;
float height = self.frame.size.height;

glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width * screenScale, height * screenScale);
...
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width*screenScale, height*screenScale, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

the last two lines simply being modified to include the scale factor.

Running this code gives me the following results:

[image: Screen Scale factor = 2]

As you can see, the image now only fills the lower left quarter of the screen, but I can confirm the image is only scaled, not cropped. Can anyone help me work out why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not actually being scaled, it is that you are actually drawing the frames to a defined size that you defined prior to allowing the render buffer to be 2X the size in both directions.

Most likely what is going on is you defined your sizing in terms of pixels rather than the more general OpenGL coordinate space which moves from -1 to 1 in both the x and y directions (this is really when you are working in 2D, as you are).

Also, calling:

```
float width = self.frame.size.width;
float height = self.frame.size.height;
```

will return a size that is NOT the retina size.  If you NSLog those out, you will see that even on a retina based device, those return values based on non-retina based screens, or more generally a movement unit, not a pixel.

The way I have chosen to obtain the view's actual size in pixels is:

```
GLint myWidth  = 0;
GLint myHeight = 0;

glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES,  &myWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &myHeight);
```

In iOS, I have been using the below code as my setup:

```
-(void)setupView:(GLView*)theView{
    const GLfloat zNear = 0.00, zFar = 1000.0, fieldOfView = 45.0;
    GLfloat size;
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    size = zNear * tanf(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(fieldOfView) / 2.0);

    //CGRect rect = theView.bounds;
    GLint width, height;

    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &width);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &height);

    // NSLog(@"setupView rect width = %d, height = %d", width, height);

    glFrustumf(-size, size, -size / ((float)width / (float)height), size /
           ((float)width / (float)height), zNear, zFar);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glLoadIdentity();
```

}

The above routine is used within code I am testing on both retina and non-retina setups, and is working just fine.  This setupView routine is an overridable within a viewController.

Comment: So I understood those calls would return the point size, rather than the pixel size, which is why I was then multiplying it by the screen scale factor, which would give the pixel value. I'm trying to set the size of the renderbuffer, so those calls surely wouldn't be useful since they are referencing the size of the same renderbuffer?

Comment: In all of my iOS OpenGL code, I use those routines to gain actual pixel size, then use myWidth, and myHeight to set the render buffer size.  In my draw code, I then have to be aware of what I am trying to display from a physical size perspective, and display using per pixel math that calculates a floating point movement for each pixel (normalize the -1 to 1 out to the pixel size returned by the two above routines).

Comment: Also my camera image texture and overlays are being drawn between between -1 and 1, if that's what you're meaning. I haven't hard-coded any resolution values anywhere.

Comment: When I call those routines they return zero for the height and width values though, which I thought would be due to the fact that the renderbuffer size hasn't been set yet (that's the task I'm trying to accomplish).

Comment: Ah so I was misunderstanding what glRenderbufferStorage was doing. I do actually perform those calls earlier and store those values. Switching in the values returned by those routines however doesn't fix my size problem. Do you have any other suggestions of where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found.

I found out that in my draw function I was setting the glViewport sizes based off the glview.bounds.size, which is in points rather than pixels. Switching that to the be set based off the framebufferWidth and framebufferHeight solved the problem.

```
   glViewport(0, 0, m_glview.framebufferWidth, m_glview.framebufferHeight);
```